# High Sierra and Mojave OS

Tags: xcode

my professor wants us to update our Mac OS to Mojave and I’m currently on High Sierra. Is there any difference with these OS if we are using xCode?

Answer (score 0):

If you're already rocking Xcode 10 on High Sierra, there's nothing noticeable except for the dark mode
(Though you should ideally be running it on Mojave)

If you're still rocking Xcode 9, updating to Mojave and Xcode 10 might be a noticeable upgrade. Here's Apple's documentation of change logs/improvements on Xcode versions: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/whats-new/

I guess this is the most generic way to answer your question :-)